# Approximate the values of a matrix given a function built with a given base vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-algebra, linear-regression

First of all forgive me if the title sounds a bit confusing. English is not my native language so although I'm fluent at it, some technical terms might not be correct. Let me know if and how I can improve it.

I was given an assignment on a machine learning course with Python. I have a table of values (I believe I can call it a matrix) that can be visualized with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


h = np.array([x for x in range(0,5500,500)])
v = np.array([x for x in range(0,65,5)])

print(h.shape,v.shape)

y = np.array([83.4, 78.7, 74.1, 69.7, 65.4, 61.3, 57.4, 53.6, 50.0, 46.5, 43.2,
 75.1, 70.8, 66.6, 63.3, 59.5, 55.7, 52.7, 49.2, 46.4, 43.2, 40.5,
 69.7, 65.7, 62.2, 58.8, 55.2, 52.0, 48.9, 45.9, 43.1, 40.3, 37.6,
 64.4, 61.0, 57.6, 54.2, 51.0, 48.0, 45.1, 42.4, 39.7, 37.1, 34.7,
 59.9, 56.6, 53.3, 50.3, 47.5, 44.6, 41.9, 39.3, 36.8, 34.4, 32.1,
 56.1, 53.0, 50.1, 47.2, 44.5, 41.9, 39.3, 36.9, 34.6, 32.3, 30.2,
 53.3, 50.4, 47.5, 44.8, 42.2, 39.8, 37.4, 35.1, 32.8, 30.7, 28.6,
 50.9, 48.1, 45.4, 42.8, 40.3, 38.0, 35.7, 33.4, 31.3, 29.3, 27.3,
 48.7, 46.0, 43.4, 40.9, 38.6, 36.3, 34.1, 31.9, 29.9, 27.9, 26.1,
 46.4, 43.9, 41.4, 39.0, 36.8, 34.6, 32.4, 30.4, 28.5, 26.6, 24.8,
 44.1, 41.7, 39.3, 37.1, 34.9, 32.8, 30.7, 28.8, 26.9, 25.2, 23.4,
 41.7, 39.4, 37.2, 34.9, 32.9, 30.9, 29.0, 27.2, 25.4, 23.7, 22.0,
 39.3, 37.2, 34.9, 32.9, 31.0, 29.1, 27.3, 25.6, 23.8, 22.3, 20.7])

# Confirm lengths all match
y.shape
len(y) == len(h)*len(v)

###################################
# Matrix visualization with Pandas
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(y.reshape(13,11), index=v, columns=h)

print(dataframe)
```

For contextualization, the lines are the speed (m/s), and columns are height (m) of an airship. The values are the thrust (N - Newton) of an aircraft.

The problem to solve is:

> Approximate the matrix with a function built with the elements of the following base: {1, v ,h , v², h², vh, v³, h³, v²h, vh², v²h², v³h, vh³}

**First of all, I don't really understand what lies in the heart of the question. Those are values of betas in a multivariate linear regression right? What are the advantages of doing this with so many betas?**

With the help of a friend I was able to achieve the following solution:

```
base = []
i = 0
j = 0

for i in range(0,len(v)):
    for j in range(0,len(h)):
        base.append([1, v[i], h[j], v[i]**2 , h[j]**2, v[i] * h[j],
                    v[i]**3, h[j]**3, (v[i]**2) * h[j], v[i] * (h[j]**2),
                    (v[i]**2) * (h[j]**2), (v[i]**3) * h[j], v[i] * (h[j]**3)])

base = np.array(base)
base.shape
base_df = pd.DataFrame(base)
print(base_df)


base_tp = np.transpose(base)
d = np.dot(base_tp, base)
inv_d = inv(d)
# print(inv_d.shape, base_tp.shape)
x = np.dot(inv_d, base_tp)
beta = np.dot(x, y)

print(beta.shape,beta)
```

And this is what I have so far. I believe it is correct but I won't stick my neck out for it. Should I have reshaped the initial y array with `y.reshape(143,1)` before proceeding? If so why?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this is a multiple regression problem where aircraft velocity(v) and height (h) are used to model thrust (t) - that is "thrust = model(velocity, height)". This means that some mathematical formula is to be modeled using the given data and the mathematical functions supplied, such as v squared, height cubed, etc. The simplest way is to use "linear regression" where different combinations of the given functions are used as in "t = a + b*h + c*v", etc. The "1" that is given would mean "a*1" which is just "a", this is usually referred to as an offset parameter.

I made a 3D scatterplot of the data and is appears to have some abrupt discontinuity, here is an image showing this:

[image: still.png]

however it is easier to see with this 3D animated GIF (6.6 MBytes) of the data rotating in 3-space: http://zunzun.com/temp/static_images/rotation.gif

To help you in creating the 3D scatterplot, 3D surface plot of the function, and a 3D contour plot here is some Python code for a *non*-linear fit that creates these plots with matplotlib.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, alpha, beta):
    t = data[0]
    p_p = data[1]
    return a * (t**alpha) * (p_p**beta)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    # this example uses curve_fit()'s default initial paramter values
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, I don't really understand what lies in the heart of the
>   question. Those are values of betas in a multivariate linear
>   regression right? What are the advantages of doing this with so many
>   betas?

The task at hand here is to assume that the `y` values can be modeled in terms of the `v` and `h` values as a linear combination of the specified basis elements. The *betas* you mention are the coefficients with which individual basis elements contribute.

Formally, one is looking for a solution to `A . betas = y`, where `y` enters as a 1D array (vector) and the matrix elements `A_ij` contain the `j`th basis element evaluated for the `v` and `h` values corresponding to `y_i` (i.e., the values of `v` and `h` for which `y_i` was "measured").

Since the problem is overdetermined (matrix `A` has more rows than columns), one has to somehow relax the definition of "solution" - one possible candidate is the least-squares solution which can be formally obtained (as you have already implemented in your question) as the solution to the set of equations `(A^T.A) . betas = A^T . y`.

However, the matrix `(A^T.A)` tends to be quite ill-conditioned so instead of calculating explicitly the inverse, I would suggest to either use a least-squares solver provided by numpy:

```
beta, res, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(base, y, rcond = -1)
```

or to use [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) instead:

```
beta = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(base), y)
```

Now, if you check the maximum relative error of the obtained "fit" as:

```
np.max(np.abs((np.dot(base, beta) - y) / y))
```

then the approach based on calculating direct inverse of the matrix `A^T.A` yields approximately `0.05`, while the least-squares solver provides a value of `0.01`.

> Should I have reshaped the initial y array with y.reshape(143,1)
>   before proceeding?

If you don't reshape `y`, the solution `beta` will have a shape of `(13,)`, while if you do `y.reshape(143, 1)`, then the shape of `beta` will be `(13, 1)`, nevertheless both cases are equally valid...